# ¿Como puedo enviar mas de un parámetro mediante URL en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Trato de enviar mas de un parámetro mediante una URL en laravel, no se si sea la forma correcta de hacerlo, porque estoy recibiendo error.

Este es mi código en una de mis vistas:

```
<a href="{{url('anexaradultos',$idguest->id,$idbook->id,$idroom->id)}}">Agregar adultos</a>
```

Mi función dentro del controlador es la siguiente:

```
public function anexadult($idguest,$idbook,$idroom){
      $idguest =Guests::find($idguest);
      $idbook = Books::find($idbook);
      $idroom = Rooms::find($idroom);
      return view("agregar_organizador2",array("idguest"=>$idguest,"idbook"=>$idbook,"idroom"=>$idroom));     
}
```

Al dar click en el enlace donde mando la URL me muestra el siguiente error:

```
https://localhost:8081/anexaradultos/1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Comment: podrías indicarnos la definición de tu ruteo (`Route`) para dicho método.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La función del controlador la veo bien. Te digo los cambios que creo que te pueden solucionar el problema.

En rutas:

```
Route::get('anexaradultos/{idguest}/{idbook}/{idroom}', [
    'as' => 'anexaradultos',
    'uses' => 'Tu_Controller@anexadult',
]);
```

El link lo puedes llamar así:

```
<a href="{{url('anexaradultos', ['idguest' => $idguest->id, 'idbook' => $idbook->id, 'idroom' => $idroom->id])}}">Agregar adultos</a>
```

En la [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing) hay más información si la necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

voy a complementa la respuesta en la siguiente

en el link
http://localhost/arbolito/public/Procedimiento_arbole/index/2

en el router seria asi arbolito\routes\web.php

```
Route::get( 'Procedimiento_arbole/index/{idguest}', [
    'as' => 'Procedimiento_arbole',
    'uses' => 'Procedimiento_arboleController@index',
]);
Route::get( 'Procedimiento_arbole/index', [
    'as' => 'Procedimiento_arbole',
    'uses' => 'Procedimiento_arboleController@index',
]);
```

**en el controlador seria **

```
class Procedimiento_arboleController extends Controller
{
public function index($name='All')
    {


        if ($name=="All") {
            $procedimiento_arbole = Procedimiento_arbole::all();
        }else{
            $procedimiento_arbole = Procedimiento_arbole::all();


        }
        $Procedimiento_estado = Procedimiento_estado::all();

        $datos="es una prueba de control ";
        $this->datos= $datos;
        return view('Procedimiento_arbole.index', ['name' => $name,'listmysql' => $procedimiento_arbole,'listmysqlProcedimiento_estado'=>$Procedimiento_estado] )
        ->with('entidad_territoria_id', $entidad_territoria_id)

    }
```

}